# Script para uma biblioteca particular SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

> Imagine que um cliente entrou em contato e solicitou a criação de um sistema para cadastrar os livros da biblioteca particular, em sua conversa com ele você chegaram nas seguintes tabelas que o sistema deverá conter:
>
> - CATEGORIA
> - EDITORA
> - AUTOR
> - LIVRO
>
> Na conversa de vocês ficaram definidas as seguintes Chaves e Referências:
>
> Tabela CATEGORIA:
>
> - ID é chave primária.
>
> Tabela AUTOR:
>
> - ID é chave primária.
>
> Tabela EDITORA:
>
> - ID é chave primária.
>
> Tabela LIVRO:
>
> - ID é chave primária.
> - ID_CATEGORIA é chave estrangeira e referencia ID da tabela CATEGORIA.
> - ID_AUTOR é chave estrangeira e referencia ID da tabela AUTOR.
> - ID_EDITORA é chave estrangeira e referencia ID da tabela EDITORA.
>
> Baseando-se nas tabelas, chaves e referências estabelecidas com seu cliente  elabore:
>
> 1. O DER (Diagrama de Entidade e Relacionamento).
> 2. Um script contendo os comandos SQL de criação das tabelas juntamente com os campos (atributos) e seus respectivos tipos (usando os conceitos aplicados em aula e sua criatividade).
> 3. Crie os comandos de inserção de cada tabela, onde cada tabela deverá ter no mínimo 5 registros.
>
> Atenção:
> Não esqueça de criar as chaves primárias e os relacionamentos estrangeiros  entre as tabelas.

A faculdade se nega a tirar qualquer duvida ou corrigir algo por ser um trabalho valendo nota, entao peço a ajuda de vcs. Segue o que fiz até agora:

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRICAO VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE EDITORA(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE AUTOR(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE LIVRO(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_AUTOR)     REFERENCES AUTOR(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_EDITORA) REFERENCES EDITORA(ID)
); 


INSERT INTO CATEGORIA(DESCRICAO) VAUES('ADMINISTRACAO');

INSERT INTO CATEGORIA(DESCRICAO) VAUES('TECNOLOGIA');

INSERT INTO CATEGORIA(DESCRICAO) VAUES('GASTRONOMIA');

INSERT INTO CATEGORIA(DESCRICAO) VAUES('EDUCACAO FISICA');

INSERT INTO CATEGORIA(DESCRICAO) VAUES('MEDICINA');

INSERT INTO EDITORA(NOME) VAUES('ARTICA');

INSERT INTO EDITORA(NOME) VAUES('MEDIUM');

INSERT INTO EDITORA(NOME) VAUES('DIAD');

INSERT INTO EDITORA(NOME) VAUES('ZEN');

INSERT INTO EDITORA(NOME) VAUES('MERIZ');

INSERT INTO AUTOR(NOME) VAUES('MERLINDO PC');

INSERT INTO AUTOR(NOME) VAUES('COSTA VAZ');

INSERT INTO AUTOR(NOME) VAUES('LERIANA LUP');

INSERT INTO AUTOR(NOME) VAUES('AREHT BLAE');

INSERT INTO AUTOR(NOME) VAUES('MOMA FENG');

INSERT INTO LIVRO(NOME,ID_CATEGORIA,ID_AUTOR,ID_EDITORA) VALUES('ERA TOYOTA',1,1,1);

INSERT INTO LIVRO(NOME,ID_CATEGORIA,ID_AUTOR,ID_EDITORA) VALUES('Angular 10',2,2,2);

INSERT INTO LIVRO(NOME,ID_CATEGORIA,ID_AUTOR,ID_EDITORA) VALUES('Salada de Frutas - A a Z',3,3,3);

INSERT INTO LIVRO(NOME,ID_CATEGORIA,ID_AUTOR,ID_EDITORA) VALUES('Exercícios de Rotina',4,4,4);

INSERT INTO LIVRO(NOME,ID_CATEGORIA,ID_AUTOR,ID_EDITORA) VALUES('Medicina Alternativa',5,5,5);
```

Na linha 19 do script, quando e pra criar a FKey de categoria, me apresenta esse erro:

```
ERROR: column "id_categoria" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora vendo o script todo pude perceber o problema, que está aqui:

```
CREATE TABLE LIVRO(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ID_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID),  <- ONDE ESTÁ ID_CATEGORIA?
FOREIGN KEY (ID_AUTOR)     REFERENCES AUTOR(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_EDITORA) REFERENCES EDITORA(ID)
);
```

Note que, está fazendo referencia a uma coluna que não existe na sua tabela "ID_CATEGORIA", assim como "ID_AUTOR" e "ID_EDITORA". Para adicionar a *contraint* da chave estrangeira, a coluna precisa existir nada tabela, basta então adicionar essas colunas:

```
CREATE TABLE LIVRO(
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  ID_CATEGORIA INT,
  ID_AUTOR INT,
  ID_EDITORA INT
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_AUTOR)     REFERENCES AUTOR(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_EDITORA) REFERENCES EDITORA(ID)
);
```